When can a vector field on a curve $\gamma: I\rightarrow M$ be extended to a neighborhood of the image of $\gamma$?
Let $M$ be a manifold and $\gamma: I\rightarrow M$ a curve. According to some notes I have on Riemannian geometry, a vector field $X: I\rightarrow TM$ can be extended to a neighborhood of the image of $\gamma$ is $\gamma$ is a proper embedding. The counterexample is an inclusion $\gamma:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $X(t) = \frac 1t \frac{d}{dt}$.
What is the condition of being a proper embedding that is meant here and why is it sufficient for the vector field to be extendable?

That implies that the image will be an embedded submanifold. Proper, as always, means that the preimage of any compact set is compact. At any rate, think tubular neighborhood of (the image of) $\gamma$.
